# ReSharper configuration

Tags: resharper

Ok I am trying to do some research on how to set up ReSharper. My company would be interested in settings up the DotSettings file on a network drive that employees point to so resharper can work, instead of having to tell employees to pull down the new updates. Any advice on where I can look or if this is even possible?

FYI We are currently using version 6.1 of ReSharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under settings you would go to manage. From there you would import the saved profile on the network drive. The way settings are do is is cascaded so local settings changes wouldn't impact the company settings file

Comment: That wouldn't work because it would still require a email notification that the settings have been updated and everyone needs to get the update. We were looking for an automatic solution but it appears there is not a solution.